Check if a file has been copied or not in the last 5 days
I want to check if a file has been copied or not, in the last 3 days. Is there any way to know this in osx? The following does not work.
find . -atime -72h -ls 


No, this isn't possible.
Copying a file does not involve "opening" it, so checking the last open time won't do what you want.
